# Rails 7 - Have to Restart Server to See Any Changes. How to Fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I am working on a Rails 7 app.

In order to see any changes (even of text), I have to stop the server, and restart it.

I am using ./bin/dev to start the server, but the same 'no change' situation exists even when starting the server with rails s.

The server output:

```
breakdiving@DESKTOP-6VLHQ8A /mnt/c/coding/contactpoints (get/form-to-submit) $ ./bin/dev
17:08:39 web.1  | started with pid 651
17:08:39 js.1   | started with pid 653
17:08:39 css.1  | started with pid 654
17:08:40 css.1  | yarn run v1.22.19
17:08:40 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.19
17:08:40 css.1  | $ sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules --watch
17:08:40 js.1   | $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets --watch
17:08:40 js.1   | [watch] build finished, watching for changes...
17:08:53 web.1  | => Booting Puma
17:08:53 web.1  | => Rails 7.0.4.2 application starting in development
17:08:53 web.1  | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
17:08:58 web.1  | Puma starting in single mode...
17:08:58 web.1  | * Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.1.2-p20) ("Birdie's Version")
17:08:58 web.1  | *  Min threads: 5
17:08:58 web.1  | *  Max threads: 5
17:08:58 web.1  | *  Environment: development
17:08:58 web.1  | *          PID: 652
17:08:58 web.1  | * Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
17:08:58 web.1  | * Listening on http://[::1]:3000
17:08:58 web.1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
17:09:00 css.1  | Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
```

Pertinent lines from development.rb

```
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded any time
  # it changes. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join("tmp/caching-dev.txt").exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      "Cache-Control" => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

Thank you for any insight.  It's very bothersome, and hoping someone reading this can offer some insight.

Comment: does the file tmp/caching-dev.txt exist in your app?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be there.  Just checked the tmp folder in my text editor file tree for the app.

Comment: @LesNightingill got any thoughts on how I may be able to fix this?

Comment: sorry, I can't think of anything. It's really a long shot, but generate a new rails app and look at development.rb to see if there's anything in there that is different from your app's development.rb. It's all I can come up with!